# Exception in sqlite3 query c#

Tags: c#, sqlite

below is my code to insert data into the sqlite3 database, table name and query seems to be correct but whenever I insert data exception comes up.

[image: Image of exception]

```
        query = "INSERT INTO Order (Name, Quantity, SUPrice, Desc, Total, Paid, Remain) VALUES ( '" + orderDto.Name + "', '" + orderDto.Quantity + "', '" + orderDto.SUPrice + "', '" + orderDto.Description + "', '" + orderDto.Total + "', '" + orderDto.Paid + "', '" + orderDto.Remaining  + "')";
        connection.Open();
        command = new SQLiteCommand(query, connection);
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        connection.Close();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to escape `order` with double quotes `"`, because `order` is the keyword.

but there is an issue in your code [SQL-injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

I would use parameters instead of connecte SQL string.

```
query = "INSERT INTO \"Order\" (Name, Quantity, SUPrice, Desc, Total, Paid, Remain) VALUES (@Name,@Quantity,@SUPrice,@Description,@Total,@Paid,@Remain)"
connection.Open();
command = new SQLiteCommand(query, connection);
command.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@Name", orderDto.Name);
command.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@Quantity", orderDto.Quantity));
command.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@SUPrice" , orderDto.SUPrice));
command.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@Description" , orderDto.Description));
command.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@Total", orderDto.Total));
command.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@Paid" , orderDto.Paid));
command.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@Remain" , orderDto.Remaining));
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
connection.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using string.Format for DB queries, it's less messy.

```
query = string.Format("INSERT INTO Order (Name, Quantity, SUPrice, Desc, Total, Paid, Remain) VALUES ( '{0}', '{1}', '{2}', '{3}', '{3}', '{4}', '{5}')", orderDto.Name, orderDto.Quantity, orderDto.SUPrice, orderDto.Description, orderDto.Total, orderDto.Paid, orderDto.Remaining);
```

Also try your query in DB browser for SQLite, you can test your queries first then put then in your code.
http://sqlitebrowser.org/